# Treeview remove property problem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, treeviewitem

i added a SampleNode to the treeview.

if i remove any node from SampleNode,

like,

```
TreeNode[] nodes = this.SampleNode.Nodes.Find(node.Text, true);
      if (nodes.Length > 0)
      {
        int j = nodes[0].Index;
        if (nodes.Length > 0)
          this.SampleNode.Nodes[j].Remove();
      }
```

it is deleted in treeview but not in SampleNode.
Why does this happens?

what is the solution?

Comment: Sorry, this question is not very clear.  How are you determining that nodes aren't being removed from SampleNode? If they aren't being displayed in the tree they should be removed from the Nodes collection.

Comment: i said like the node is removed from treeview where the samplenode is added.   But it is removed from samplenode

Comment: That is the expected behavior - we remove the node from the TreeView by removing it from SampleNode.Nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code to add some nodes.

```
 TreeNode root = new TreeNode("Root");

 root.Nodes.Add("1", "Sampl1");
 root.Nodes.Add("2", "Sampl2");
 root.Nodes.Add("3", "Sampl3");
 treeView1.Nodes.Add(root);
```

Code to search and delete a node,

```
TreeNode []nodes= treeView1.Nodes.Find("1", true);

 if (nodes.Length != 0)
  {
    //nodes[0].Remove();
    //or
    treeView1.Nodes.Remove(nodes[0]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is might be that you are removing nodes by the index in the nodes array - not by their position in the tree.

Try replacing:

```
this.SampleNode.Nodes[j].Remove();
```

With:

```
this.SampleNode.Nodes.Remove(nodes[0]);
```

Comment: +1 Greg. @curiosity : debug your app. What is? -  node.text (it must be a key).